# how to dynamically set width of a div based on one of the subdivs

Tags: html, css

I have this structure. A div that has 2 other divs inside of it

```
<div id='main'>
  <div id='1>
      Text I want to have overflowo: hidden 
  </div>
  <div id='2'>
      Text that I want do decide the width of main div 
  </div>
</div>
```

If the text in div 2 overflows I want the main div to expand,
but if the text in div 1 overflows the max-width specified I want the main div
to remain the same width

Not sure if this is possible using just css

I may have oversimplified the example at the top. Not dealing with pure text.

[image]

Want the bottom part with the buttons drive the width but if there is something in the list that is too long it will get clipped.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS grid with grid-template-columns: fit-content() is handy for this:

```css
#main {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display:inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: fit-content(0ch);
  width: min-content;
}

#one {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#two {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id='main'>
  <div id='one'>
      Text I want to have overflowo: hidden  sdfs  sdf sdf js fsj flskdj sklfjsd flksjf skldjsdlfk js flkjs flskdj sdlkf
  </div>
  <div id='two'>
      Text that I want do decide the width
  </div>
</div>
```

**Added 2nd example from your edited question**
To make make the first width just overflow, use the following css:

```css
#main {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display:inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: fit-content(0ch);
  width: min-content;
}

#one {
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

#two {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id='main'>
  <div id='one'>
      Text I want to have overflowo: hidden  sdfs  sdf sdf js fsj flskdj sklfjsd flksjf skldjsdlfk js flkjs flskdj sdlkf
  </div>
  <div id='two'>
      Text that I want do decide the width
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `#main` display `inline-block`, so it would always wrap it's child elements.

Than add `white-space: nowrap` to `#d2` ([CSS does not work with integer ID names](https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/))

```css
#main {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}

#d1 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  max-width: 100vw;
}

#d2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id='main'>
  <div id='d1'>
      Text I want to have overflowo: hidden 
      Text I want to have overflowo: hidden 
      Text I want to have overflowo: hidden 
      Text I want to have overflowo: hidden 
      Text I want to have overflowo: hidden 
      Text I want to have overflowo: hidden 
      Text I want to have overflowo: hidden 
      Text I want to have overflowo: hidden 
      Text I want to have overflowo: hidden 
  </div>
  <div id='d2'>
      Text that I want do decide the width of main div 
      Text that I want do decide the width of main div 
      Text that I want do decide the width of main div 
      Text that I want do decide the width of main div 
      Text that I want do decide the width of main div 
      Text that I want do decide the width of main div 
      Text that I want do decide the width of main div 
      Text that I want do decide the width of main div 
      Text that I want do decide the width of main div 
      Text that I want do decide the width of main div 
      Text that I want do decide the width of main div 
  </div>
</div>
```